# How to cast a void* to int in 64-bit platforms, using C?

Tags: c, casting, 64-bit

I am a linguist in charge of a C program, so please excuse me if the answer is obvious. I have the following code:

```
typedef struct array_s {
  (...)
  void **value;
} array_t;
typedef array_t *array_pt;

array_pt array_new (int size) {
  (...)
  array->value = (void **)malloc(size*sizeof(void *));
}

void* array_get (array_pt arr, int i) {
  return arr->value[i];
}

int main () {
  int a = 1234;
  int *ptr = &a;

  array_pt array = array_new(1);
  array_add(array, ptr);

  printf("%i\n", (int)array_get(array, 0));
}
```

It is supposed to provide me with a multi-purpose array (for storing `int` and `char*`, if I understood I can only use `void`), and I guess there are no problems of allocating/freeing. However, I cannot get to cast it into anything useful (i.e., get back the "original" int/char*), and for what I understood it could be because I am in a 64-bit system and the size of a pointer to `void` is different from the size of a pointer to `int`/`char*` (the program is supposed to be used in both 64 and 32 bit systems). I tried using `intptr_t` and other alternatives, to no luck.

How can I be sure that the code will accept any data type and work on both 32 and 64 bit systems? Thank you.

EDIT:

Sorry for not adding `array_add`, here it is:

```
unsigned int array_add (array_pt array, void *ptr) {
  (...) // get the next index
  // allocate if needed
  array->value = (void **)realloc(array->value, array->size*sizeof(void *));

  array->value[index] = p;
}
```

Comment: Where is the definition of `array_add`???

Comment: What about using size_t?

Comment: Is the accepted answer doing wht you really wanted to do? The fact that you are talking about 64- and 32-bit systems suggests that you wrere actually intending to cast and store `int` values in your array, while the accepted answer stores pointers to `int` in the array (`int *`). So, what is it you were trying to do?

Comment: @AndreyT I am sorry, I really don't know... I had accepted the answer as it did solve the problem, but kept open as people continued commenting. I am quite new to programming, I supposed the 32/64 bit were playing a role in the problem -- I would just like to keep it clean and not use tricks that would work on 64 but not on 32.

Comment: @rogue: I wasn't -- I put it in the code only to keep it short; in reality I have a function like void *ptr = malloc(size); if (!ptr) exit(1); return(p) which is what is being cast. It may be wrong, but hopefully at least I know what I should not be doing... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to dereference your pointer:

```
int* temp = array_get(array, 0);
printf("%i\n", *temp);
```

However, I strongly recommend avoiding this type of approach.  You're basically giving away the small amount of help the compiler in C will normally provide - purposefully trying to make non-typesafe arrays.

Comment: Thank you for such a fast answer, Reed. However, gcc is complaining:

prova.c:14: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
prova.c:14: error: invalid use of void expression

Comment: You could do it on one line, but it's going to be really ugly ;)

Comment: It worked, thank you! Just so I can try to understand (pointers are a bit of black magic for someone who did a major in Medieval Literature), how could you do it in one line?

Comment: @Reed Copsey: In one line it would be ugly specifically because you'd have to use a *cast* to `int *`. You used two lines, yout you kept a cast for some reason (???), which makes it exactly as ugly as one-line approach would be. The whole point of using a temporary typed pointer is that you can do it without a cast: `int* temp = array_get(array, 0)`.

Comment: This should work: `printf("%i\n", *((int*)array_get(array, 0)));`   - You just need to cast it to an int pointer, then dereference the int pointer.

Comment: @AndreyT: +1 Yes - I had left it in just so it was obvious why it was working - but I took it out, esp. now that I added the details in my last comment.

Comment: @Giacomo: Is this not working, now?  (Just wondering why you marked it as answer, then unmarked it again...)

Comment: @Reed Copsey: I suspect that what the OP wanted is to `int` values directly in the array (cast to `void *`), not `int *` pointers. In other words, you answer "works", but it does not do what the OP intended to do.

Comment: @Reed Copsey: I was thinking that marking it as solved would prevent people from commenting! I marked it again, thank you very much (and yes, it is working, I am trying to understand its secrets now). :)

Comment: The extra parentheses are unnecessary - `*(int *)array_get(array, 0)` is fine.  To the OP, be aware that the array is not storing the integer itself - it's storing the location of some integer variable (in the case of your example, the variable `a` in `main`).  If that integer variable goes away (say, because the function it was declared in returns), then the array is now holding an invalid location.

Answer (score 3):

You need to decide what is it you are trying to do in this case.

**(1)** If you want to use your `void *` array to store `int` values (*actual* `int` forcefully converted to `void *`), then you should add these `int` values to the array as follows

```
int a = 1234; 

array_pt array = array_new(1); 
array_add(array, (void *) a);
```

and then get them back from array as follows

```
int a = (int) array_get(array, 0); 
printf ("%d\n", a);
```

or simply

```
printf ("%d\n", (int) array_get(array, 0)));
```

That last part is exactly what you did, but you got the first part wrong.

This is a cast-based approach, which is ugly in many ways, but it has certain practical value, and it will work assuming `void *` is large enough to hold an `int`. This is the approach that might depend on the properties of 32- and 64-bit systems.

**(2)** If you want to use your `void *` array to store `int *` values (pointers to `int`), then you should add these `int` values to the array as follows

```
int a = 1234; 

array_pt array = array_new(1); 
array_add(array, &a);
```

and then get them back from array as follows

```
int *pa = array_get(array, 0); 
printf ("%d\n", *pa);
```

or simply

```
printf ("%d\n", *(int *) array_get(array, 0));
```

This approach is perfectly safe from any portability problems. It has no 32- or 64-bit issues. A `void *` pointer is guaranteed to safely hold a `int *` pointer or any other data pointer.

If that was your intent, then you got the first part right and the last part wrong.

Either this or that. You code appears to be a strange mix of the two, which is why it doesn't work, and which is why it is impossible to figure out from your original message which approach you were trying to use.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense... I wanted to code to store both int values and pointers to chars (strings). Maybe I should have two different strutures?

Comment: You absolutely should use two different structures; this approach is error-prone, dangerous, and a nightmare to debug.  Remember that any small integer value will crash the program if you try to dereference it; in fact, most random integers will.

Comment: @Giacomo: Well, you are saying that you wanted to store `int` values, yet you accepted an answer that stores `int *` values. So, again, what is it you wanted to do?

Answer (score 0):

intmax_t should be an integer type that is 32 bits on 32bits compilers and 64bits on 64bit compilers. You could use %j in your printf statement to print intmax_t. The size of pointers on one system is always the same - independently of them pointing to int, char or void.

```
printf("%j\n", (intmax_t)array_get(array, 0));
```

Comment: array_get returns a pointer - he's (I think) trying to print the value of the int being stored, not the memory address...

Comment: Well, then your answer above should help. :) It really depends on what the array_add does.

Comment: I am sorry know, but it does not work: gcc says

warning: format ‘%i’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code? It says "%j" (spell: Jay) instead of %i.